# Not a top of the page but window.scrollY equals 0 on chrome mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

Not a top of the page but window.scrollY equals 0 on chrome mobile browser.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the Chrome browser mobile emulation tools doesn't take scroll position into account. Any code you write should work fine on actual devices.

Comment: I have tested whis code on real mobile device and have same results. Device: android 4.4.2, chrome 61.0.3163

Comment: [Mozilla developer entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) page suggests using `window.pageYOffset` for cross-browser compatibility. Can you check if that works?

Comment: I scrolled to the top of the page and
measured window.pageYOffset. It 
resulted in 0. After the measurement 
I have scrolled down a bit and 
measured again. After the 7th 
measurement window.pageYOffset 
resulted in 73 (http://shot.qip.ru/00KqwF-3YtZ2dJXb/)

Comment: window.pageYOffset still always returns 0 for me. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) entry linked above, reports that window.scrollX/Y should be fully supported in latest android chrome, but I still always get 0..

Answer (score 9):

This is a late answer but this problem is still a recurrent one... For some obscure reason, Chrome on Android requires that you set "minimum-scale=1" in the "viewport" meta of your page. Not doing so causes the scrollY value to start increasing only after a good portion of the page is already scrolled (I'm assuming this is because without this setting, the viewport's height is somehow considered larger than the screen's height).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1">
```

Comment: this works but only if you don't want the user to be able to pinch in and out properly. While setting minimum scale to a lower number enables pinch zooming out, the scrollY returns become 0 again when the user is not at the specified minimum value :(

Comment: This seems to have solved an issue I spent hours on in chrome & firefox devtools, where after closing modal window, page would always scroll to 0 / top even though I had window.scrollTo(0, y) where y > 0. The issue was only present in mobile / responsive design mode - in browser mode the scrollTo() worked as expected. Does anyone know if this causes issues on real devices?

Comment: Very good 2023!!!

Comment: Thank you good sir. Took me a good hour of googling and experimenting to find this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed wrong scroll computations by the following css rule on mobile chrome

```
@media screen and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
    html, body {
        overflow: auto !important;
    }
}
```